# About `elasticsearchTemplate.stream()` function all data in the elasticsearch database

Tags: elasticsearch

Why am I already using .withPageable(new PageRequest(0, 10000), but the elasticsearchTemplate.stream() funtion still returns all the data in the elasticsearch database. I think it will return 10000 datas, but it return all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```js
public void scrollSearchTest2() {
    SearchQuery searchQuery =
        new NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withQuery(QueryBuilders.boolQuery())
            .withIndices("log-warn-event")
            .withPageable(PageRequest.of(3, 10))
            .build();
    CloseableIterator<Warning> stream = elasticsearchTemplate.stream(searchQuery, Warning.class);

    List<Warning> list = new ArrayList<>();
    while (stream.hasNext()) {
      list.add(stream.next());
    }

    System.out.println("---------------------------------");
    list.forEach(System.out::print);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I add `.withPageable(PageRequest.of(3, 10))` like this, but still got all the data, I only want 10 size of them.